# Link not working after text indent:-9999px

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to replace the text with a image . when i indent the text to -9999px. the image is not clickable . How can I make the image click-able?

[image]

#### jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $("#left_pane").css("left","-300px");
  $("#middle_pane").css("left","0px");

  $(".toggle_right_pane").toggle(function() {       
  $('#left_pane').animate({ left: '0' }, 500);
  $('#main_pane').animate({ left: '213' }, 500);
  }, function() {       
    $('#left_pane').animate({ left: '-300' }, 500);
    $('#main_pane').animate({ left: '-15' }, 500);
  });
});
```

#### CSS

```
#left_pane{
  float:left;
  display:block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
/*    background: grey; */
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1
}


#main_pane{
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  left:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid green;
  background: url("panel-close-arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 2px 2px transparent    ;
  padding: 21px 10px;
  right: 0;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  display:block;
  width:350px;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="left_pane">
  <!--Content Here-->
</div>
<div id="main_pane">
  <a class="toggle_right_pane" href="#">show/hide</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `9999` and `99999` are way different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Not the direct answer, but why are you not using `img` tag instead?

```
<div id="main_pane">
  <a href="#"><img src="panel-close-arrow.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This makes more sense, and if you're worried about screen readers simply set your img alt to show/hide.

Comment: I have 2 images one for open and one for close that will be manupaluted by jquery. so i was thinking of putting the image in a class and thinking of addClass and removeClass as needed

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I'd change text-indent to -9999px, just 4 digits.
secondly, you're missing the rules for

```
#main_pane a {}
```

which should roughly have:

```
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

If you could give us a link to an online, live version of your example, i'd fix your issue right away

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, main issue with text-indent property.if you use it with #main_pane it will shift complete a tag, so use it with a tag

```
#main_pane{
  border:2px solid green;
  background: url("panel-close-arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 2px 2px transparent; 
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  width:350px;
  padding: 21px 10px;  
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  left:0px;
  right: 0;
}

#main_pane a{
    text-indent: -99999px;
    display:block;
    height:100%
    }
```